# Fetch As Google Ajax is blocking

Tags: ajax, parse-platform, google-search-console

I am newbie Parse and I have a problem. I want to use parse classes for dynamic content such as blog posts. Everyting works as expected there is no problem ; but when I try to fetch as google in Google Webmaster Tools it says AJAX blocked. So google will not index this content anyway.

when I follow the link I saw this below.

[this is what I  see when follow class link](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-gkh16l7RpfI/VZPtGekGA2I/AAAAAAAABJQ/alTmG2abF_E/s1600/Untitled2.png)

So google crawler try to get ajax content but it comes to it with a ConnectionFailed aka 100 error. (I tested it to show in a label on page what returns in parse query error callback. So I see what renders google)

Am I doing something wrong is this an expected behaviour ?

Anyone knows how to solve this ?

Btw: I am hosting this website on heroku with custom domain over https (with cloudflare dns redirected and free ssl)

I also deployed to Parse Cloud Hosting unfortunately the result is same :(

This is the full result of the Fetch as Google :

[full page result of fetch as google](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-APB38R8ncIY/VZQGYUqVZsI/AAAAAAAABJg/vw6SYikHTWA/s1600/Untitled3.png)

Comment: Getting the same thing, especially with the recent Google news about their Googlebot, not sure how we'll be able to benefit from the change: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Answer (score 1):

The page at `https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore` is asking for authentication, and it's throwing a `401 Unauthorized` status code for unauthorised requests. That's already a problem.
Besides that, the page at `https://api.parse.com/robots.txt` is currently showing

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Googlebot can't access that page because it's disallowed for crawling in the first place, but even if it could access it, it would run into an authentication gate which it wouldn't be able to pass.

If the content from that URL (`https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore`) is essential for the page where its referenced/used, you would have to work with Parse to allow crawlers access those URLs. 
If it's not essential, then you can safely ignore that warning.